# What does this contractive sequence mean? - Calculus I

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

My teacher gave us a definition to what he calls a contractive sequence which basically means that:

being $u(n)$ a sequence of real numbers: $u(n)$ is a contractive sequence if there's a constant $C∈ ]0,1[$ such that
$$ |u_{n+1}-u_n|\le C|u_n-u_{n-1}| $$
for a large enough n value.

I've tried to understand this as sequence whose two consecutive terms decrease at a certain rate (C). However, I cannot fully understand this. If someone could help me visualize this or understand it better I would appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can say that the distance between two consecutive terms decreases faster than a geometric sequence.

Comment: Please consider using MathJax. Tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Contractive sequences are convergent. Thats why they are interesting.

Comment: Hint: Try to show $\{u_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I'm going to guess a typical Calc 1 class has not covered Cauchy sequences.

Comment: we covered Cauchy sequences before this one, but I didn't understand it either lol. I know a Cauchy sequence is a convergent sequence but I don't know the relationship between it and a contractive sequence.